# iOS app crashing on high numbers of table cells with sliders

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uislider

Noob here.

I am programmatically creating a number (`globalCount`) of UISliders in iOS with Swift 3. A `grandTotal` float value is divided between these sliders' values and when one is changed they all adjust to sum to 100% of the `grandTotal`. No slider goes below their minimum of 0 or above their maximum of 100.

All is working well for numbers of sliders less than 7. As soon as I add 7 or more. I get a crash when trying to update the cell's slider values with the underlying struct values.

I've moved the cell update functionality to its own function to try isolate the issue. I still get a crash. The crash is

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

and appears on the `let loopCell` line.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what this is about? Why is it working for low numbers and not higher numbers of cells? Is this a conditionals thing?

This is the cell update function

```
func updateCells() {
    for i in 0...globalCount - 1 {
        let loopCell: MyTableCell = ((myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:i, section: 0))) as? MyTableCell)!
        loopCell.valueLabel.text = String(structData[i].value)
        loopCell.cellSlider.value = structData[i].value
    }
}
```

**My UI:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93bXD.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cellForRow(at:)` returns `nil` if a table view cell is not visible (currently offscreen).  You are crashing because you are force unwrapping `nil`.  Instead, use optional binding (`if let`) to safely unwrap the value:

```
func updateCells() {
    for i in 0..<globalCount {
        if let loopCell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? MyTableCell {
            loopCell.valueLabel.text = String(structData[i].value)
            loopCell.cellSlider.value = structData[i].value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you saying it's offscreen? Or is that the 2nd column is off screen?

Comment: Educated guess. OP said "adding 7 or more".  I figured he was running out of screen real estate forcing the a cell to be offscreen.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Will give this a go

Answer (score 0):

It's due to use of force unwrapping it is crashing .

Best handy way is to use **if let** statement to check data is there or not , since **if let** does it (unwrapping).